# The logical basis of mathematics

Tags: logic

in the last few months I'm feeling like I'm losing my confidence in math. I recently started a degree in math at 15, in school I was the best - I graduated with a score of 100 out of 100 but now that I see the formalization, every step feels like something is missing. The logical basis of mathematics suddenly seems problematic and shaky to me. I researched the subject and it only got worse! (Gödel's theorems shocked me - we have no guarantee of non-contradiction in mathematics?). Can someone please explain the matter to me in an orderly manner please? What does mathematics rely on and what actually prevents contradictions? Can contradictions arise as a result of exploring new concepts/definitions such as limit and matrices for example? And how can we use mathematics in everyday life (or in Physics) when it uses theoretical axioms?
Mathematics is made up of human logic and imagination but maybe our logic is misleading us?

These questions may be silly but I still wonder about them - I didn't find an unequivocal answers.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: My advice for you (however difficult it is to hear): You are probably entering a level of understanding where both mathematics and philosophy are needed to make sense of each other. Continue onwards with your journey and whilst those questions will probably find unequivocal answers, they will certainly grow over time. These things take time.

Comment: No issue with [Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/): they are mathematical theorems, and thus we "accept" them exactly because we agree that mathematics can produce real knowledge.

Comment: In addition, they are specific results applying to formal systems, and "formalization" is a tool to be used to improve our existing mathematical knowledge: but mathematics existed well before strict formalization (and survived to G's Th).

Comment: Goedel's results did not lead to a breakdown of mathematics. In contrary ! This discovery led to stronger formal systems in which we can prove statements that cannot be proven in weaker theories (see Goodstein sequences for an example). For the daily life or physics, Goedel's results do not have any consequences whatsoever.

Comment: And the set theory recovered very well from the discovery of an utterly surprising contradiction of an earlier (too strong) version. It was modified and everything was fine. The dangers for our daily life surely do not come from math and its logic. And you have no reason not to trust mathematics. However, physical theories cannot be justified ONLY by the math it uses, although this unfortunately is often done.

Comment: If you do not trust that a proof system $P$ cannot lead to contradiction, then why would you trust a proof within system $P$ that system $P$ cannot lead to contradiction? Even if we restricted mathematics to the degree that our formal mathematical system could prove its own consistency, there is still some philosophical circularity there. So I don't see how Godel's incompleteness theorems really change anything from that point of view.